# Variable ' ' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android

In 'Main' im trying to use function declared in class Bluetooth, and having error as in title.

Here is the code

```
    ImageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bluetooth.wlaczBT();
        }
    });
```

I have class bluetooth and within it i have a method wlaczBT (in english its Turn  on BT).

But have bluetooth underlined in red unfortunetly. 
How can I used that method in Main class?

This is how i declared variable bluetooth (in Main ofc)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
```

i tried to add "final" before "Bluetooth", but the app crashed while instaling on phone.

Comment: I should point that method wlaczBT works properly.
If I use it in class Bluetooth it is working.
But I want to use that method after user uses a Button.

Comment: what is the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: in stack trace ive got this
"
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference"

Comment: You don't need final. You need a field

Comment: You're supposed to be trying to get `MainActivity.this.bluetooth`, not `bluetooth.this`, since you aren't within that class

Comment: Actually, you should make it final. And dig deeper why the crash is thrown. From what I see from stacktrace - it is some internal Android error. Maybe you should init something before. What is the class Bluetooth? Is it public class from some library? If so - please share the link so I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make bluetooth a global variable. That means declare it before the onCreate() but initialize it in onCreate ().